Double integral $\int \int_R \sqrt{1-x^2-y^2} \mathrm{d}x\mathrm{d}y$ (from the surface integral $\int \int_S z^2 \mathrm{d}S$)
I have this double integral over a region $R\in \mathbb{R}^2$, which is the projection of the surface $S: \{x^2+y^2+z^2=1| \; x\geq0,y\geq0,z\geq0\}\in \mathbb{R}^3$ (located in the 1st quadrant).
I want to evaluate $\int \int_R \sqrt{1-x^2-y^2} \mathrm{d}x \mathrm{d}y$ using polar coordinates ($x=r\cos{\theta}$, $y=r\sin{\theta}$) over the projected region $R$. It is supposed to evaluate to $\pi/6$.


Here is what I did:
$\mathrm{d}x\mathrm{d}y=r \mathrm{d}\theta\mathrm{d}r$ and $x=r\cos\theta, y=r\sin\theta$. Putting that in the integral gives:
$$\int \int_R \sqrt{1-(r\cos\theta)^2-(r\sin\theta)^2} r \mathrm{d}\theta \mathrm{d}r = \int \int_R \sqrt{1-r^2(\sin^2\theta+\cos^2\theta)} \ \ r\mathrm{d}\theta \mathrm{d}r = \int \int_R \sqrt{r^2(1-r^2)}\mathrm{d}\theta\mathrm{d}r$$
I think the bounderies of the projected surface $R$ is $r\in[0,1]$ and $\theta\in[0,\pi/2]$. Inserting this gives:
$$\int_0^1 \int_0^{\pi/2} \sqrt{r^2(1-r^2)}\; \mathrm{d}\theta\mathrm{d}r=\frac{\pi}{2} \int_0^1 r\sqrt{(1-r^2)}\; \mathrm{d}r$$
And now I am sort of stuck. How do I evaluate $\int r\sqrt{1-r^2} \mathrm{d}r$?

Consider $r^2 = u$.

By the way, your title is misleading. This is an ordinary double integral, as $R$ is a planar region.

Let $1-r^2=u$ so that $-2r\,\mathrm dr=\mathrm du$. Then,
$$\int r\sqrt{1-r^2}\,\mathrm dr=\int-\frac12\sqrt{u}\,\mathrm du$$
Then, it is straightforward.
Hope this helps. :)
